# .net equivalent for Java's Swing TableModel?

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, swing, datagridview

I'm a Java developer which is just starting to learn .net. When coding my user interfaces with Java we can count with the TableModel interface which makes the process of representing objects in data tables something really easy.

In .net what is the equivalent? I don´t want to show data which is stored on databases, but the tabular representation of the attributes of a group of objects. How can I do that on .net DataGridView class? Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) class. It does *not* have to be connected to a database in order to be populated.

Check out the other classes in the [`System.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax3wd0k9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) namespace, as there might be something that will suit your needs even better (the [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=VS.100).aspx) class which can contain many `DataTable`s and even add some referential integrity between them).